# Case expression in where clause PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, where-clause

How could I query something like this in PL/SQL?

```
declare
  l_batch_type number := 1;
select
  *
from table t
where 
  case 
    when l_batch_type = 1 then ('A', 'B')
    when l_batch_type = 2 then ('C', 'D')
    when l_batch_type = 3 then ('E', 'F')
    when l_batch_type is null then null end in t.batch_type;
```

I'm getting SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
It is obviously something wrong with ('X','Y') values and in operator,
but I can't figure out how to match right syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with `('A', 'B')`? Check if batch_type is one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd generally want to use simple boolean logic rather than putting a `case` statement in a `where` clause

```
where (l_batch_type = 1 and t.batch_type in ('A', 'B'))
   or (l_batch_type = 2 and t.batch_type in ('C', 'D'))
   or (l_batch_type = 3 and t.batch_type in ('E', 'F'))
```

Since `null` is never equal to anything (and never unequal to anything), I'm not sure whether your `l_batch_type is null` condition is intended to add anything to the logic.