# Oracle with CASE Statement in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle

Below is my attempt to include a `CASE STATEMENT` in a `WHERE` clause, it's not working. Anyone knows how I can correct this?

```
PROCEDURE GetBatchTotals(pEntityName VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL) IS

BEGIN

  -- Sample Query
  SELECT
    e.ColumnName
  FROM
    Schema.TableName e
  WHERE
  (
    CASE
      WHEN pEntityName IS NULL THEN
        e.ColumnName != '' -- Just to select everything in the table
      ELSE
        e.ColumnName = pEntityName
    END
  );

END GetBatchTotals;
```

I cannot seem to make sense of the examples I've seen already posted. Here's another attempt without using a CASE STATEMENT but returns no result:

```
SELECT
  e.ColumnName
FROM
  Schema.TableName e
WHERE
  (pEntityName IS NULL AND e.ColumnName != '') OR
  (pEntityName IS NOT NULL AND e.ColumnName = pEntityName);
```

Anyway, here's the true sample query that returns no result:
[image]

And then here's the table with data:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second query should work. Dis you try running it locally? Also standalone select statement is moot in a procedure. Give sample data and replicate the problem.

Comment: I've added extra info to the original question...

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty string in Oracle. If you want your query to work, you need to turn `!= ''` into `is not null`. Or maybe get rid of that condition entirely if you want to select all rows, regardless of whether e.columnname is null or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never forget that in Oracle SQL the `''` literal (empty string) is the same as `NULL`, hence your predicate `e.ColumnName != ''` is equivalent to `e.ColumnName != null` which always evaluates to `NULL`.

Second problem is that you are trying output a boolean value from your `CASE`. No, Oracle can't use boolean expressions as results from functions. (Let's consider `CASE` to be a function, as I cannot remember a more proper name for these language constructs now.)

Try it this way:

```
PROCEDURE GetBatchTotals(pEntityName VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL) IS
BEGIN
  -- Sample Query
  SELECT ColumnName
  FROM TableName e
  WHERE
    (pEntityName IS NULL AND e.ColumnName is not null) OR
    (pEntityName IS NOT NULL AND e.ColumnName = pEntityName);
END GetBatchTotals;
```

There's a few more issues with your code, let's have them fixed:

(1)
Don't use `varchar`, use `varchar2` instead. A strange "enhancement" of Oracle's, don't ask.

(2)
For equality predicates with non-`NULL` values you may leave off the predicate `pEntityName is not null` from one of the `AND`-s, it will be implied.

(3)
Predicate `e.ColumnName is not null` really filters out the rows where `e.ColumnName` is `NULL`, which is something different from your original idea to query all rows regardless of their `e.ColumnName` value.

(4)
Either loop through the query results or bulk fetch them to a collection or return them as a ref cursor. In PL/SQL you **must** put the query results into something! Let's loop through the query results and spool the `ColumnName` contents to server output...

```
PROCEDURE GetBatchTotals(pEntityName VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) IS
BEGIN
  for rec in (
    SELECT ColumnName
    FROM TableName e
    WHERE pEntityName IS NULL -- Just to select everything in the table
      OR e.ColumnName = pEntityName
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.ColumnName);
  end loop;
END GetBatchTotals;
```

Comment: `e.ColumnName is null`... I think you mean `is not null` here? (Since the original queries had `e.columnname != ''`)

Comment: Thanks, I get the concept. Yes you're right the query is actually for a cursor...

Comment: @Boneist, thank you. Obviously, there's no sense hurrying when writing code. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I liked nop77svk answer, however, he never really clarified the issue with CASE (ie how to write the logic using CASE properly).
So for completeness, here's how you handle that logic using CASE.

```
  PROCEDURE GetBatchTotals(pEntityName VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) IS

  BEGIN

    -- Sample Query
    SELECT
      e.ColumnName
    FROM
      Schema.TableName e
    WHERE
     1 = CASE
           WHEN pEntityName IS NULL AND e.ColumnName IS NOT NULL
              THEN 1
           WHEN e.ColumName = pEntityName 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END
    );

  END GetBatchTotals;
```

In this particular situation, nop77svk solution is likely the slightly easier/cleaner code :)

Comment: I did clarify the issue with `CASE` (... being that boolean values are not valid in SQL context, that is), but you're right, I did not propose an actual alternative with `CASE`.

Comment: @nop77svk: sorry, that's what I meant :) that you didn't show how to do CASE "properly" .. ;) heh (updated answer a bit to clean up that mud :) )

Answer (score -1):

Try this structure in your sql worksheet with your metadata:

```
declare
  l_object_name varchar2(20) := null;-- your objects name
begin

  for l_rec in (
    select
      e.object_name
    from
      all_objects e
    where
      (l_object_name is null and 
      1=1) or
      (l_object_name is not null and 
      e.object_name = l_object_name))
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Object found: '||l_rec.object_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Test it.

Comment: why bother with the `and 1=1`? Just leave that off.

Comment: Yes, its optional. For aesthetics purpose - some use it for pointing out that is is "IN ALL" etc.

Comment: The OP's question was "how I can correct this?". This does not explain what is wrong in the question and just presents the OP with a different (anonymous) PL/SQL block, without any explanation why or how it would solve their issue.

Comment: First, the OP gave the abstract code (2nd to be precise), which should have worked, but claimed that it did not. I built a more specific code, a template, that gives the desired output. We had a certain break-point, to determinate what he did wrong, what was missing, if we continued to test it further. Why this approach is bad, according to you?