# oracle where clause with case when

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to avoid dynamic sql. I need to check a value from a parameter, and depending on it, apply the right clause.

ex:

```
select * from table
WHERE 1 =
CASE
    WHEN channel = 1 AND REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1--only numbers
    WHEN channel = 2 AND LOGIN LIKE 'MI|%' THEN 1
    WHEN channel = 3 AND LOGIN NOT LIKE 'MI|%' AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '') THEN 1 --except what is being filtered on case 1 and 2
    ELSE 0
END
```

Sample DATA from LOGIN column:

```
VIC.A67923
2013836
257551
GAB.A53272
MI|1234
MI|5345
```

Running the filters individually, they are working fine, but testing assigning the proper value to the parameter, it's returning wrong data.

e.g. when passing 1, it should return only those that have numbers, but it's returning data that has text on it too.

Comment: **Please** show sample table data

Comment: @OldProgrammer done. So for value 1, it should return only rows 2 and 3; for value 2 only rows 5 and 6; and for value 3, rows 1 and 4.

Comment: You realize that all of your cases return a value of 1, right? That's why you always get all rows back.

Comment: @DStanley I thought that only the proper clause would return 1 to match the 1 from the where clause, is that wrong?

Comment: they _all_ return 1.

Comment: I know, but it`s because the WHERE clause starts with WHERE 1 = .... then the proper clause will return 1 to filter that row.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it - every single case you have (even the `DEFAULT` fallback if no cases match) return `1` so ANY row will match your WHERE clause.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to correct the problem. Either add an answer showing the correction or add the correct query to your question.  It confuses others who are reading your question trying to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't anchor and repeat your digit check. Anchor it to the beginning and end of the string. And all of your cases return 1, so it ends up doing nothing

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablea
 WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN channel = 1 AND REGEXP_LIKE (login, '^[[:digit:]]*$')
               THEN 1                                                                                      --only numbers
               WHEN channel = 2 AND login LIKE 'MI|%'
               THEN 1
               WHEN channel = 3 AND login NOT LIKE 'MI|%' AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (login, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
               THEN 1                                                     --except what is being filtered on case 1 and 2
               ELSE 1
           END
```

Comment: If I change to 1,2,3,4 ... then the WHERE 1= will be valid only when channel =1?

Comment: Got it. It was my else that should be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your case to

```
CASE
    WHEN channel = 1 AND REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '[[:digit:]]') 
        THEN 1--only numbers
    WHEN channel = 2 AND LOGIN LIKE 'MI|%' 
        THEN 2
    WHEN channel = 3 AND LOGIN NOT LIKE 'MI|%' AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '') 
        THEN 3 --except what is being filtered on case 1 and 2
    ELSE 4
END
```

or perhaps, if `channel` is an input parameter:

```
WHERE channel =
    CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '[[:digit:]]') 
            THEN 1--only numbers
        WHEN LOGIN LIKE 'MI|%' 
            THEN 2
        WHEN LOGIN NOT LIKE 'MI|%' AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(LOGIN, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '') 
            THEN 3 --except what is being filtered on case 1 and 2
        ELSE 4
    END
```

Comment: I was following this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44002586/1384539

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do now - see my edit.

Comment: Got it. It was my else that should be 0. Thanks